# Thread interruption doesn't stop executing infinite task

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, completable-future, timertask

I have following snippet of code:

```
@Async("executor")
    public CompletableFuture<List<SecondObject>> getSecondObject(List<FirstObject> firstObject) {

        CompletableFuture<List<SecondObject>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        final int timeout = 5000;
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        //Thread created by configuration
        final Thread executorThread = Thread.currentThread();

        //Method responsible for thread interruption
        final TimerTask interruptTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Thread timerTaskThread = Thread.currentThread();
                System.out.println("Exception for thread "+executorThread.getName()+" is thrown");
                System.out.println("Timer task thread "+timerTaskThread.getName()+" is issued");
                executorThread.interrupt();
                future.completeExceptionally(new InterruptedException());
            }
        };
        //Schedule set for thread interruption
        timer.schedule(interruptTask, timeout);
        System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is created.");
        System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is executing a task.");
        List<SecondObject> secondObject = Collections.emptyList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            i--;
        }
        future.complete(secondObject));
        timer.cancel();
        System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has been terminated.");

        return future;
    }
}
```

and the code that tries to access `CompletableFuture`.

```
List<FirstObject> firstObject = Collections.emptyList();
List<SecondObject> testedList = null;
CompletableFuture<List<SecondObject>> future = sectionsService.getSecondObject(firstObject);
            try {
                testedList = future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {

            }
```

The problem I have encountered is that when I call `get()` method then despite having each `TimerTask` tracking the timeout for each new thread created with `@Async`, infinite task (here it is infinite `for loop`) blocks main thread completely. Interrupt flag for `@Async` thread is thrown but thread itself isn't stopped - program executes infinite `for loop` despite thread being interrupted. Program waits until `get()` returns something. I need `TimerTask` to actually stop thread when timeout is exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

[`executorThread.interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) will *not* stop the thread. All it does is set the thread's [`isInterrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) flag.

If you interrupt a thread that happens to be waiting in any one of several different standard library methods (e.g., `Thread.sleep()`, `thread.join()`, `object.wait()`) then the library method will throw an `InterruptedException`. If you interrupt a thread that happens to be waiting for input, then certain other things happen (see the Javadoc for `interrupt()`.)

But in your program, the `executorThread` is doing none of those things. It's just doing trivial computations, so no exception will be thrown. If you want the interrupt to be recognized, then you'll have to write code that explicitly checks the flag.

```java
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            i--;
            if (executorThread.isInterrupted()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        future.complete(secondObject));
        ...
```

---

IMO, Correctly using interrupts can be tricky in some situations. Have a look at the tutorial if you want to learn more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: But in the case that I run some method that could be taking long time - how could I prevent it from exceeding timeout or worse - making it run infinitely? I don't want all code to stop on certain, inifnite task

Comment: @Thorvas, I don't understand what you are asking. My answer, above, shows how you can change your `getSecondObject` function so that it will complete the future when it receives an interrupt from the `timerTaskThread`. Is that not the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Small correction: Correctly using interrupts is tricky in *most* situations. You’re better of using a future which supports cancellation with interruption (which `CompletableFuture` does not)…

Answer (score 1):

```
future.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);
```

Comment: ```future.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);```
works similarly. Code throws TimeoutException but is still processed on infinite task.